# Delete an anonymous user in Firebase without Exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have used *Anonymous sign-in* for my users. I want my users to be able to sign out if they want (by clicking on a button). Now, I want to delete the account when the user signs out. That's why, I want to use

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
user.delete();
```

But, in the Firebase documentation, it is mentioned that if a user is signed in for a long time, then we must reauthenticate the user before deleting, otherwise it may throw an exception. Now, the question arises, how can I reauthenticate an anonymous user? I am a beginner and this is my first project where I am using Firebase. My concepts maybe wrong. Please help.

Comment: Where did you read that you should reauthenticate an anonymous user?

Comment: I learnt that I should reauthenticate a user. Now, I don't know whether it is applicable for anonymous users or not. That's why I asked this question. Thanks @Alex Mamo

Comment: Could you tell me if you have a server available or Firebase Functions? before answering your question, since I have had the same problem as you and I have already solved it

Comment: You said *in the Firebase documentation, it is mentioned that if a user is signed in for a long time, then we must reauthenticate*. Please show me those docs. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Frank sir, Do you remember I was having a problem where my FirebaseDatabase was automatically getting disconnected and you had told me to enable debug logging? I did and it says _Network upload failed. Will retry later. code, error: 0, java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "app-measurement.com"; No address associated with hostname_.

Comment: That domain makes it seem related to Analytics. But it seems unrelated to this question.

Comment: But this error is displayed sometimes, not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement to re-authenticate users before sensitive operations (such as deleting their account) only applies for providers that require the user to enter credentials. For anonymous users, there is no need to reauthenticate them before deleting their account.